# Browser permission for microphone and camera - web app

Tags: browser, web-applications, permissions

We're developing a web-based app that need microphone and camera permission to operate. Once the user rejects those permissions (even unintentionally) there is currently no way or at least we don't see it to prompt different browsers to again display the permissions box and to overwrite the existing choices that were made.

What are the options here to somehow force the browser or to circumvent the settings so the user can give the permission?

The problem with the users is that they simply don't know how to deal with this kind of browser options.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make the user very aware that their choice is important so maybe they will not deny the request?

Comment: There are some notices about it, but some of them still accidentally deny it. After that there is no way back because they of course don't have the knowledge to deal with permissions. So basically there is no other alternative?